# Auto Copy Row imports too fast?

Tags: scripting, google-sheets

I'm using Google Sheets. Here's the scenario:

**WB #1**: Raw Data created from Form Data entered by customer. To be left alone.

**WB #2, Sheet A**: Importrange codes to bring in data from WB #1 and a few fields added to change some info to abbreviations.

**WB #2, Sheet B**: Daily Workable, which currently will bring in each row from Sheet A if a "Y" is typed into the first column.

I am hoping automate this so when Sheet A is filled automatically from WB #1, it automatically sends a copy to Sheet B without having to type a "Y" as a trigger.

I thought I could set it to another field like an Email field, so that when the row automatically comes in from WB #1, it fills it with a email address which will always contain a "@". So I set the code to do that, but the rows are filled in so quickly that it doesn't move them to Sheet B.

When we were testing last night and still using the script that had a row move when a "Y" was placed in the first column, if you typed the "Y" in too quickly to each row, it wouldn't move that row over to Sheet B. If you do that exact same thing slowly, it moves them all over correctly. So it seems that auto copy is working too fast.

How can I do that?

Comment: Can you post your code and a link to your spreadsheet or a copy of it?

Comment: You can try using `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` which applies all pending changes.  You may also need to use `Utilties.sleep(milliseconds)` which pauses the code for a number of milliseconds.

Comment: @JacobEdmond 
I am not receiving email messages when both of you responded so I apologize I am just now seeing theses.

I will try to make a sample to share. Its not my business I am doing this for so I don't want to share without permission. 
Sandy, can you tell more more about the Utilities.sleep ...or maybe point me in the right direction for a good website that explains how to use it?
Also, can you tell me why someone was allowed to edit my post?!?! I worded it the way I wanted to and not liking that someone can come in and change it.